# Firebase iOS SDK - Count connected users

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase

I'm using the Firebase iOS SDK to build a chat system that will let my users to connect to some random "rooms" where they can chat together. Inside the room I want to display to them the total number of people connected at the moment. The problem is that I don't know how to do that count. The number of users connected should be updated on connects and disconnects of particular users. I don't know where to start and what to do.

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more context in terms of how your code is structured already and where in it you would need the count to appear, as well as details around code controlling connects and disconnects. This question as it stands is probably too broad for this forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple :)

Whenever a user authenticates/joins a room save them to the list of active users.

**Swift**

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "<your-firebase-db>")
ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock { authData in
  if authData != nil {
    // 1 - Get the ref
    let activeUsersRef = Firebase(url: '<your-firebase-db>/activeUsers')
    // 2 - Create a unique ref
    let singleUserRef = activeUsersRef.childByAutoId()
    // 3 - Add them to the list of online users
    singleUserRef.setValue(authData.providerData["email"])
    // 4 - When they drop their connection, remove them
    singleUserRef.onDisconnectRemoveValue()
  }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"<your-firebase-db>"];
[ref observeAuthEventWithBlock: ^(FAuthData *authData) {
  Firebase *activeUsersRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"<your-firebase-db>/activeUsers"];
  Firebase *singleUserRef = [activeUsersRef childByAutoId];
  [singleUserRef setValue: @"Whatever-the-key-is"];
  [singleUserRef onDisconnectRemoveValue];
}];
```

The snippet above will maintain a list of active users.

All you need to do now is display the count.

**Swift**

```
// Listen to the same ref as above
let activeUsersRef = Firebase(url: 'firebase-db.firebaseio.com/activeUsers')
activeUsersRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) in
  var count = 0
  // if the snapshot exists, get the children
  if snapshot.exists() {
    count = snapshot.childrenCount
  }
})
```

**Objective-C**

```
Firebase *activeUsersRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"<your-firebase-db>/activeUsers"];
[activeUsersRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  NSUInteger count = 0;
  if ([snapshot exists]) {
    count = snapshot.childrenCount;
  }
}];
```

Comment: :) thanks, but could you please provide me with a objective-c example to follow???

Comment: It would be really helpful if you mention such requirements in your question, instead of after somebody wrote an answer for you.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm going do that next time.

Comment: @user1341993 - The conversion is simple too. I added that as well though.

Comment: I dont understand why   [singleUserRef setValue authData.providerData["@email"]]; ? why email? can i call it what ever??

Comment: It needed to be @"email" not "@email". You can call the key whatever you like. This answer assumes you're using email and password authentication.

Comment: i'm not using any authentication in my app, beside that there is a problem with:"  [activeUsersRef observeEventType: (FEventTypeValue " it dont know what FEventTypeValue is to compile

Comment: beside that :  if [snapshot exists]  is wrong and it says error

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors. My apologies, I wrote it off the cuff. As for authentication, you should be using auth for this type of situation. Even if it's just anonymous auth. If you don't you'll have little to no control over your local user.

Comment: @DavidEast I am using cocoapods for firebase. Adding Firebase and Firebase/Database in it. Now, I am importing #import "Firebase.h" still I am not able to use Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"<your-firebase-db>"]; It's throw me an error. Please tell me where I am wrong